# Can't understand the difference between 2 equations

Tags: javascript, if-statement, leap-year

I am new to Javascript, and have been trying to figure out the best possible equation for a Leap year calculator. I have written the solution like this:

```
if ((year % 4 ===0 && year % 100 !==0) || (year % 4 ===0 && year % 100 ===0 && year % 400 ===0)) {
  alert("Leap");
} else {
  alert("Not Leap");
}
```

After having done that, I googled other ways and found out it could be written like this:

```
if ((year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || (year % 400 ===0)) {
  alert("Leap");
} else {
  alert("Not Leap");
}
```

But I don't understand how it could be written like that, because knowing the conditions for leap years:

- If year is divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100 = Leap
- If year is divisible by 4 and is divisible by 100 and divisible by 400 = Leap
- Otherwise its not a Leap year.

I don't understand the logic behind the second code sample, to me, it is as if:

- If year is divisible by 4 and not divisible by 100 = Leap
- OR
- Only, if year is divisible by 400 = Leap (not including other conditions)
- Otherwise its not a Leap year

Could someone please explain why the second code sample is also valid, and how it is interpreted?

Comment: Does it help if I explicitly state that **400 is divisible both by 4 and 100, so when a number is divisible by 400, it is also divisible by 4 and 100 for sure, even without further checks**?

Comment: You have an if statement with multiple conditions. JS checks from top/down and left/right so grouping with the parenthesis is key. I took your code, added some fix to the first one and made a comparison https://es6console.com/k9j2aqg1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for a leap year is if the year is divisible by 4 and not by 100, or year is divisible by 400.

Mathematically, anything divisible by 400 is divisible by 4 and by 100, this is the reason why the leap year is if (x % 4 AND NOT x % 100) OR (x % 400).

You can see it like this factor decomposition: 400 = 4 * 100, so any number that may be written as `n * 400` may be written as `n * 4 * 100`, so your condition is just redundant.

Comment: Khan Academy has an excellent page on [Factors & Divisibility](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:intro-factoring/a/intro-to-polynomial-factors-and-divisibility)